# Why QuerySet returns anything but the list of String values?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been playing with QuerySets for two days now, and there is something I want to understand better.

It is all very convenient that QuerySet returns Objects and I had a chance to appreciate that.

What I don't understand is why it doesn't give you an option to return a list of String values.

For example: I need to choose a distinct (unique) `type` from my table `Property`. I could do that in a couple of ways:

```
Property.objects.values('type').order_by().distinct()
```

> [{'type': u'Flat'}, {'type': u'House'}, {'type': u'Villa'}]

or

```
Property.objects.values_list('type').order_by().distinct()
```

> [(u'Flat',), (u'House',), (u'Villa',)]

In both cases there is either a dictionary of Unicode values, or a tuple with a Unicode value 0_o

How do I specify a QuerySet that would return a list of string values?

P.S. We can convert the results of the QuerySet to a list of Strings, but then the result won't be a QuerySet no more.

P.P.S. I need in for my ModelChoiceField, and I will explain why I need it that exact way if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pass `flat=True` to `values_list` to get a flat list of strings.

```
Property.objects.values_list('type', flat=True).order_by().distinct()
```

Comment: This option didn't fit me at the time ( my ModelChoiceField returns this error when i select any of the values : "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices"), but this answers the question perfectly.